# WordPress query_posts display past dates

Tags: wordpress, date, post

I have my page displaying only future dates which is just what I want, I have been digging around trying to find a way to query only: posts that are dated prior to todays date.

This is currently my query:

```
<?php
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'artists',
    'orderby'   => 'ecpt_featured_month',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'future'
);
```

Any ideas? If it helps, each post is an artists and they have a featured month, post = month.

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Use this one considering "ecpt_featured_month" is a custom field:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'artists',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'ecpt_featured_month'
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'future'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
// write the general code to display the post's title and date
endwhile;
```